# Black screen appears when the CEF Winform Browser loads for the 1st time

Tags: winforms, chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am using CEF Sharp - V86

I am getting this strange issue and our users have starting complaining about it.

When the cefsharp winform browser loads for the first time, it shows the black window for few mili-seconds and then it disappears.
If we reload or refresh the webpage, it does not happens.

We have recently upgraded from V79 to V86 and we did not had any issue in earlier version.

What i have tried so far is, tried setting below command line arguements but it didn't work.

settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu-compositing");

I have also tried setting
Cef.EnableHighDPISupport()

But it didn't work.

Additional Info :

Checked with Latest Version - CefSharp V88

When we load CefSharp winform browser in wpf application using winform host, a black screen appears on load for the first time for few miliseconds and then disappears.

This was not happening in earlier version.(i checked with V79 till V83).

Steps to reproduce.

Create a sample wpf application ,use windowsformhost to load cefsharp winform browser.
In constructor of winform browser, use any url. I tested with [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).
Run the application.
Notice the initial black screen appears for few miliseconds and then disappears.

Please note this happens only for the first time when the chrome winform load.

**his seems to have broken from CEFSharp v84.**

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Comment: also posted my question on cef forum :https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=18272

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the black flash. Once I removed it from the VS Form Designer, things got better. Define it as a form level object:

```
private ChromiumWebBrowser cwbPage;
```

Then in the form constructor, instantiate it and add it to a panel in the form:

```
cwbPage= new ChromiumWebBrowser("");
cwbPage.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.pnlPanel.Controls.Add(cwbPage);
cwbPage.BringToFront();
//...add any event handlers
```

Finally, pass it the string of Html or navigate to the url:

```
cwbPage.LoadHtml("<html><body>This is a test.</body></html>");
//OR
cwbPage.LoadUrlAsync("https://www.google.com");
```

Notes:

1. It still takes about 3 seconds to load the content, but at least there is no black flash.
2. I experimented and tried going back to using the VS Form Designer, and the black flash came back. I stripped almost all of the properties away from it in the VS Form generated code, but it still flashed blackly. So it does not like using the Form Designer.

Comment: Three seconds is unexpected long. What version are you using? Are there any errors in the log? Does the load time improve if you pass the url directly into the constructor? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: @amaitland I am using 91.1.230. It delays 3 seconds from when form is shown to when something is shown in the browser no matter where I set the url or the html. Setting html from constructor does not show.

Comment: Can you please fork https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample and provide an example that reproduces the problem. Please keep changes to the absolute minimum required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/91.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser__ctor_1.htm https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2668#issuecomment-510307886

Comment: @amaitland I built a new test project to see if I could replicate the black flash. It turns out that having a Microsoft WebBrowser control docked (DockStyle.Bottom) in the same area as the ChromiumWebBrowser (DockStyle.Fill) causes the latter to black flash. When I removed the Microsoft WebBrowser control, the black flash went away. It still takes 2 to 3 seconds for the Html to be rendered from when the form is shown.